# Sonar-ws-client returning 401 error even though I can perform a search in the UI

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following source code:

```
package com.sample.sonar.report;

import org.sonar.wsclient.Host;
import org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar;
import org.sonar.wsclient.SonarClient;
import org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.HttpClient4Connector;
import org.sonar.wsclient.services.*;
import org.sonar.wsclient.issue.*;
import java.util.List;


public class App {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {



        String url = "http://sample.url.com:9000";
        String login = "userid";
        String password = "password";


        SonarClient client = SonarClient.create(url);
        client.builder().login(login);
        client.builder().password(password);


        IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
        query.rules("S1081");
        query.languages("c");
        IssueClient issueClient = client.issueClient();
        System.out.println("About to Run query\n");
        Issues issues = issueClient.find(query);
        System.out.println("Ran query\n");
        List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < issueList.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println(issueList.get(i).projectKey() + " " +
                              issueList.get(i).componentKey() + " " +
                              issueList.get(i).line() + " " +
                              issueList.get(i).ruleKey() + " " +
                              issueList.get(i).severity() + " " +
                              issueList.get(i).message());
         }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Although I can log into Sonar and search the results I am getting the following runtime error

```
org.sonar.wsclient.base.HttpException: Error 401 on http://sample.url.com:9000/api/issues/search?languages=c&rules=S1081
```

I believe this is a 401 error which maps to Unauthorized.  Am I missing some sort of authentication beyond what I am doing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, basic automatism when asking for help, provide the version of SonarQube and sonar-ws-client in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SonarClient#builder()` is a static method which returns a new builder instance each time it is called. So basically, when you write:

```
SonarClient client = SonarClient.create(url);
client.builder().login(login);
client.builder().password(password);
```

your are setting the login on one Builder object, setting the password on another and doing nothing from any of them.

The object you are using is the `SonarClient` create by the method `SonarClient#create(String url)` which, indeed, has no login nor password, hence the 401 HTTP error.

What you should write is:

```
SonarClient client = SonarClient.builder()
      .url(url)
      .login(login)
      .password(password)
      .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate the help.